# Ubuntu and CentOS on the same laptop

Tags: centos

On a laptop running Ubuntu 16.04 I installed CentOS 7.

Installation appears not accessible from Ubuntu.

Using GParted CentOS partition is `/dev/sda3` marked with a red `!`, File system is `lvm2pv`,  Size 169.42 GiB.

There is no root `/` partition for CentOS.

Is installation wrong?

Answer (score 1):

`lvm2pv` means CentOS has initialized is partition as LVM physical volume (PV), and the root filesystem would be on a LVM logical volume (LV) located within that PV. LVM is very very useful in enterprise-grade systems, as it makes expanding filesystems really easy. It also allows on-line data migration from one disk to another, which is important when a large central SAN storage system is scheduled to be replaced.

If your Ubuntu set-up does not use LVM, it might not have LVM tools installed; so install them first. The package name should be `lvm2`. The exclamation mark on a `lvm2pv` partition on GParted might be just because the LVM tools are not installed: GParted needs them to fully process LVM partitions.

Once the LVM tools are installed, they might or might not activate all intact LVM volume groups automatically at boot. If the activation happens automatically, you should see one or more CentOS logical volumes when you run the `sudo lvs` command. If not, run `sudo vgchange -aly` first: it will tell LVM to activate any available LVM volume groups (VGs) locally.

The proper device name for LVM LVs will be `/dev/mapper/<VG name>-<LV name>`. It can be mounted and used just like a regular partition device that contains a filesystem, once the LVM volume group is activated first.

There will usually also be a legacy compatibility name like `/dev/<VG name>/<LV name>`, which is technically from the older version of LVM from the old 2.4.* kernels, but since this naming scheme is easier to type, it refuses to die.

Comment: Following your suggestion installed package lvm2